# Can't access nested array of scope object

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a 3 column display to mimick a kanban board. Each column does an ng-repeat on one $scope.list. I then filter each column to include the itmes I want. However now I want to be able drag an item from one column to another, and when dropping an item, perform a $http call to my rest api which will update that item.

I've looked at some tools like this - http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

But as far as I can tell this isn't any help to me as my data is all within one list.

The list that contains all the items is $scope.board and this it's JSON output.

```
  {
     "_id":"553b9fc4fee8d25ceeba6c92",
     "boardAuthor":"553b9e64fee8d25ceeba6c91",
     "title":"Board title",
     "description":"Whatever",
     "__v":0,
     "boardTickits":[
        {},
     ]
  }
```

I thought one approach could be to split $scope.board into separate arrays but I can't seem to access the nested array.

```
for(i = 0; i < $scope.board.boardTickits.length; i++) {
    if($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 1) {
        $scope.todoCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    } else if ($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 2) {
        $scope.doingCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    } else if($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 3) {
        $scope.doneCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    }
}
```

I get an error trying to get the length of the nested array.

If anybody provide some insight on accessing nested arrays that would be great, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing `.length` of `undefined` object `$scope.board.boardTickits`. You need to change you `for` loop condition form `$scope.board.boardTickits.length` to `$scope.board.length`

```
for(i = 0; i < $scope.board.length - 1; i++) { 
    if($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 1) {
        $scope.todoCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    } else if ($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 2) {
        $scope.doingCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    } else if($scope.board.boardTickits.category == 3) {
        $scope.doneCol = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm now getting a different error though - `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Any idea what it might mean?

Comment: @frank that was my bad, take a look at udpate

Comment: Yeah the loop is correct now, but what had me thinking the loop was wrong in the first place is that $scope.todoCol is empty, but it shouldn't be, because in $scope.board.boardTickits, there are 3 objects which match the criteria category == 1.

Comment: @frank I don't understand what you are tried to say, could you please create fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: Well nothing is being assigned to $scope.todoCol in the loop so I'm thinking maybe I'm still not accessing everything correctly. I tried to simplify the loop like so:
`for(i = 0; i < $scope.board.length; i++) {
        $scope.boardTickits = $scope.board.boardTickits[i];
    }`
With this i'm trying to assign all objects from the boardTickits array in $scope.board, to a new array called $scope.boardTickits, however this isn't working.

Comment: @frank could you please create a plunkr/fiddle that will give me more idea about your problem..currently its fully blur to me

Comment: I tried setting it up here - http://plnkr.co/edit/Qn0aeKJrUXUfejFdEgiP?p=preview

I've never used it before so maybe I left something out but it should give a better idea of my problem. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @frank I'll look at tomorrow..its time to bed